# boost::filesystem::path::imbue failed with default std::locale()

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, malloc

```
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale());
```

works good.

next code:

```
boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet utf8_codecvt_facet;
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), &utf8_codecvt_facet));
```

works good too.

next code:

```
boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet utf8_codecvt_facet;
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), &utf8_codecvt_facet));
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale());
```

generates error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbff6e8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

OSX 10.10.5, Xcode, boost 1.57, beginning main().

Why?

Answer (score 3):

When using the constructor taking a facet pointer the created locale takes ownership of the facet and will thus delete it in its destructor.

Here, you pass a pointer to a stack-allocated facet.